# Filing file with zeroes

Tags: c, aio-write

My file should be filled with 0. I want to do that using `aio_write` As a result my file should look like `000000000....` but as a result I get that my file is filled with garbage

```
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
s|▒^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@▒r|▒^@^@^@^@▒▒^?▒(▒▒▒▒s|▒▒
y▒^P^@^@^@^X▒▒▒
s|▒^X^@^@^@▒.....
```

I don't even imagine what's wrong. First of all I'm using asynchronous write so I need to wait when `da_aio_write` is completed

```
int da_test_wait( struct aiocb *aiorp ){
   const struct aiocb *aioptr[1];
   int rv;
   aioptr[0] = aiorp;
   rv = aio_suspend( aioptr, 1, NULL );
   if( rv != 0 ){
      perror( "aio_suspend failed" );
      abort();
   }
   rv = aio_return( aiorp );
   printf( "AIO complete, %d bytes write.\n", rv );
   return 1;
}
```

Also here is my writing function

```
 int da_aio_write(const int d, struct aiocb *aiorp, void *buf, const int count){
   int rv = 0;
   memset( (void *)aiorp, 0, sizeof( struct aiocb ) );
   aiorp->aio_fildes = d;
   aiorp->aio_buf = buf;
   aiorp->aio_nbytes = count;
   aiorp->aio_offset = 0;

   rv = aio_write( aiorp );

   if( rv == -1) {
       perror("Error da_aio_write\n");
       exit(1);
       return rv;
   }
   return rv;
}
```

and my main

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[] ){
        int sk;
        int d;
        struct aiocb aior;
        if(argc == 3){
                sk = atoi(argv[2]);
                char buffer[MB * MB * sk];
                //memset(&aior, 0, sizeof( struct aiocb ));
                d = da_open(argv[1]);
                da_aio_write( d, &aior, buffer, sizeof(buffer) );
                da_test_wait( &aior );
                da_close( d );
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
EDIT:
I know that my da_aio write ends after main because ehen I compile I get

```
File created
 dskr1 = 3 
AIO complete, 1048576 bytes write. 
closed
```

**EDIT** My full updated code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <aio.h>
 #include <errno.h>

#define MB 1024

int da_open(const char *name);
int da_aio_write(const int d, struct aiocb *aiorp, void *buf, const int count);
int da_test_wait( struct aiocb *aiorp );
int da_close(int fd);

int da_open(const char *name){
   int dskr;
   int dskr2;
   dskr = open( name, O_RDWR );
   if( dskr == -1 ){
       printf("File created\n");
       dskr2 = open( name, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
   }else{
       printf("End job!\n");
       exit(1);
   }
   printf( "dskr1 = %d\n", dskr2 );
   return dskr2;
}

int da_aio_write(const int d, struct aiocb *aiorp, void *buf, const int count){
   int rv = 0;
   memset( (void *)aiorp, 0, sizeof( struct aiocb ) );
   aiorp->aio_fildes = d;
   aiorp->aio_buf = buf;
   aiorp->aio_nbytes = count;
   aiorp->aio_offset = 0;

   rv = aio_write( aiorp );

   if( rv == -1) {
       perror("Error da_aio_write\n");
       exit(1);
       return rv;
   }
   return rv;
}

int da_test_wait( struct aiocb *aiorp ){
   const struct aiocb *aioptr[1];
   int rv;
   aioptr[0] = aiorp;
   rv = aio_suspend( aioptr, 1, NULL );
   if( rv != 0 ){
      perror( "aio_suspend failed" );
      abort();
   }
   rv = aio_return( aiorp );
   printf( "AIO complete, %d bytes write.\n", rv );
   return 1;
}

int da_close(int fd){
   int rv;
   rv = close( fd );
   if( rv != 0 ) perror ( "close() failed" );
   else puts( "closed" );
   return rv;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[] ){
        int sk;
        int d;
        struct aiocb aior;
        if(argc == 3){
                sk = atoi(argv[2]);
                char buffer[MB * MB * sk];
                int size; 
                size = MB * MB * sk;
                memset( buffer, '\0', size);
                //memset(&aior, '\0', sizeof( struct aiocb ));
                d = da_open(argv[1]);
                da_aio_write( d, &aior, buffer, sizeof(buffer) );
                da_test_wait( &aior );
                da_close( d );
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
char buffer[MB * MB * sk];
```

Stack variables are not automatically initialiased. So your buffer contains garbage. `memset` it to 0 first if that's what you want to write to file.

Comment: Thanks but then I get this
`^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^`
Here how I did it `memset( buffer, '\0', size);`

Comment: Please update your question with your new code. Also include `da_open`.

Comment: That is the expected output. Because writing all 0's to a file creates a binary file not a text file. If you want to see the 0's open the file with an editor that can view in hexl mode (like emacs). Or if you have `hexdump` use that to view the file instead of `cat` and friends.

Comment: Thanks! But if I want to create a file filled with 'A' characters? Why I get invalid arguments error in my `da_aio_write` function?  Even when I try to fill with 1 instead of 0 I get invalid argument. I know that memset second argument is `int` so with 1 memset should work.

Comment: Please give the exact code you changed and what the exact error message is. To set to all 'A' you change the memset to be `memset( buffer, 'A', size)`. There's no reason why aio_write would give an error for that. It doesn't care what is inside the buffer.